# Disable to receive address from dhcpd for one host/mac

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

I have a client in my network,
 who ask me to prevent him from getting ip address via dhcp.

He has a strange software, and can't switch off dhcp-client, but this dhcp client do something bad after it get ip.

In same vlan I have clients who needs dhcp to work.

I tryed that for isc-dhcp41-server-4.1.e,2:

```
host client_disable {                                                                                                                                                             
  hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:rr:ff;                                                                                                                                     
  fixed-address 0.0.0.0;                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Its seems like doesn't works.

I am trying to google that, but looks like its pretty strange scenarios, and I can't find anything appropriate.

Please, point me to right solution.

Comment: well, pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled solution from other answers:

1. Detect format of client mac.

   log(info, concat("Ignored Client ",binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 0, 12))));

That has output like "1:bc:ee:dd:gg:zz:pp"

Strange "1:" at beginning.

2. Add class for that

   class "ignored" {
     match if (binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 0, 12))) = "1:bc:ee:dd:gg:zz:pp";

   }
3. Insert pool and deny into subnet:

   ```
   subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {                                                                                                                                   
       pool{                                                                                                                                                                  
       deny members of "ignored";
   ```